# Landsat images with bad quality

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, landsat-7, earth-explorer

I downloaded several [Landsat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_program) images from some years between 1985 and 2014, all of them with good quality. Nevertheless the period from 2003 to 2013 is not worth it. I checked all images. Most of the images have black strips or color distortions.

Checking on the EarthExplorer page I get the same result. Is there something wrong with that period of detection, do I just have bad luck with my area, or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Screenshot from SCP plug in with the extension of my area]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Scan Line Corrector in the ETM+ instrument onboard Landsat-7 suffered a (suspected) mechanical failure in 2003, so all subsequent images suffer from the striping you are seeing in your images. The [Wikipedia page for the satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_7) has a good explanation.

[Destriping Landsat Images?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74320) addresses methods for de-striping the imagery, however, note that it is often not worth the effort.